# Why am I getting a CS1001 error in my code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, identifier

I am a complete novice at C# coding so this might be a dumb question, but I can't figure out why I keep getting this error from my Unity script. It says "identifier expected," but as far as I know I already have an identifier?

```cs
{

    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public string animator;
    public string movement;

    Vector2 (movement);
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);
        animator.SetFloat("vertical", movemnet.y);
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", movement.sqrMagnitude);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are there parenthesis around movement in `Vector2 (movement);`

Also this variable needs to be initialized with a value.

Try `Vector2 movement = new Vector2(0,0);`

Also a spelling error here `animator.SetFloat("vertical", *movemnet*.y);`

Comment: It worked; thank you, but now there’s a new error saying that I already have a definition for movement

Comment: then movement is likely already defined somewhere outside of the code snipped you have provided